# glTexParameteri segmentation fault in mac

Tags: c++, c, macos, cocoa, opengl

I try to use OpenGL glut on mac and have a segmentation fult error on following:

```
GLuint g_frameBuffer;

void render()
{
    //Clear color buffer
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    //Render quad
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
        glVertex2f( -0.5f, -0.5f );
        glVertex2f(  0.5f, -0.5f );
        glVertex2f(  0.5f,  0.5f );
        glVertex2f( -0.5f,  0.5f );
    glEnd();

    //Update screen
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char* args[] ){

    glutInit( &argc, args );
    glutInitWindowSize  ( 1000, 1000);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

    glutCreateWindow("Paintstorm");
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glGenFramebuffersEXT( 1, &g_frameBuffer );
    //Set rendering function
    glutDisplayFunc( render );
    //Start GLUT main loop
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with -framewok OpenGL, -framework GLUT, -framework Cocoa
Error have place when i add glTextParametri

Answer (score 1):

You should call glTexParameteri after your call to glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D). You may have a segfault here because you don't have a valid opengl context (you have it after glutCreateWindow)